# Azure Cross Subscription SQL Backup Without Account Credentials

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, powershell

Using `New-AzureRmSqlDatabaseExport` i'm able to export a database to a blob storage within the same subscription. However I would like to export database from subscription A into blob storage in subscription B. For security reasons it's not acceptable to expose subscription A Azure account credentials.

This is possible by creating a new server in subscription A, create a copy of db and then switch the new server to subscription B. That seems overly complicated and is affecting subscription A.

Code below is possible if I provide `Connect-AzureRmAccount` credentials for subscription A, but that's not an option.

```
New-AzureRmSqlDatabaseExport
-ResourceGroupName "SubscriptionA'"
–ServerName "SubscriptionA"
–DatabaseName "SubscriptionA"
–AdministratorLogin "SubscriptionA"
–AdministratorLoginPassword "SubscriptionA"

–StorageKeyType "SubscriptionB"
–StorageKey "SubscriptionB"
-StorageUri "SubscriptionB"
```

How can this be achieved using `New-AzureRmSqlDatabaseExport` with only providing database user/pass and not the account credentials?

Answer (score 0):

Running Azure PowerShell commands requires you to be logged in to Azure. Database users have rights only on the database, they don't have any rights on the Azure Fabric, which is what you are trying to use here.

If you must use New-AzureRmSqlDatabaseExport then you will need to provide credentials that can log on to Azure. You can limit the scope of these credentials to only have rights on this server, and only to backup databases (look at custom roles for RBAC), but you will need to use an Azure user.

Alternatively, you can look at using other tools that work at the database layer to do your export. One example is exporting a BacPac file - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-export

Answer (score 0):

The Storage account credentials are the `New-AzureRmSqlDatabaseExport` required parameters. 
[image]
Other words, we could not export an Azure SQL Database to a storage account without account credentials. 
For more details, you can see [New-AzureRmSqlDatabaseExport](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.sql/new-azurermsqldatabaseexport?view=azurermps-6.13.0)
and [Required Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.sql/new-azurermsqldatabaseexport?view=azurermps-6.13.0#required-parameters).

For security, you can [export your Azure SQL database to a BACPAC file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-export) and then upload the file to your Blob Storage in subscription B.

Hope this can helps you.